# Not able to update the props of a stateless child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-applications

I'm really new to React but I was trying to make a simple comments applet. My goal was wanted to change the display picture of each user by clicking the 'Change Avatar' button.
[image: The Applet So Far]

But the problem is that my button sits in the stateless `App` component. In-fact all the components are stateless except `Avatar`. Clicking on 'Change Avatar' does nothing but update the value of `appcounter` in console :( Any ideas how do I propogate this `counter` prop to `Avatar`? Here's the full code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';

let users = {
  1: {
    name: 'Harry',
    comment: 'Vengadium Leviosa!'
  },
  2: {
    name: 'Jason',
    comment: 'I don\'t believe in magic..'
  },
  3: {
    name: 'Copperfield',
    comment: 'Believe it '
  }
}

class Avatar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: props.counter
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.setState = {
      count: this.props.counter
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <img src={`https://robohash.org/${this.state.count}`} className='avatar' alt="User Avatar" />;
  }
}

function Comment(props) {
  return <p><b>{props.user.name}: </b>{props.user.comment}</p>;
}

function CommentBox(props) {
  return (
    <div className='comment-box'>
      <Avatar user={props.user} counter={props.counter} />
      <Comment user={props.user} />
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {

  let appcount = 0;
  function increment() {
    ++appcount;
    console.log('appcount:', appcount);
  };

  return (
    <div className='app'>
      <h2>Welcome to the Comments App</h2>
      {
        Object.entries(users).map(([key, value]) => {
          return <CommentBox user={value} counter={appcount + key} />
        })
      }
      <button onClick={increment}>Change Avatar</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: you should look at `useState` here for tracking the `appCount` variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should keep the `appcount` in the state of the `App` and pass it to the child components. That is what will cause rerender of `CommentBox` components and consequently `Avatar` components.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';

let users = {
  1: {
    name: 'Harry',
    comment: 'Vengadium Leviosa!'
  },
  2: {
    name: 'Jason',
    comment: 'I don\'t believe in magic..'
  },
  3: {
    name: 'Copperfield',
    comment: 'Believe it '
  }
}

function Avatar(props) {
  return (
      <img src={`https://robohash.org/${props.counter}`} className='avatar' alt="User Avatar" />
  );
}

function Comment(props) {
  return <p><b>{props.user.name}: </b>{props.user.comment}</p>;
}

function CommentBox(props) {
  return (
    <div className='comment-box'>
      <Avatar user={props.user} counter={props.counter} />
      <Comment user={props.user} />
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  const [appcount, setAppcount] = useState(0);

  function increment() {
    setAppcount(appcount + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div className='app'>
      <h2>Welcome to the Comments App</h2>
      {
        Object.entries(users).map(([key, value]) => {
          return <CommentBox user={value} counter={appcount + key} />
        })
      }
      <button onClick={increment}>Change Avatar</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Good eye! Thanks.

Comment: I had no idea about react hooks yet, but thanks for the correction!

Comment: I could be solved with "normal" state as well. This just seemed easier to write.